# SQL Server Index rebuild with no space

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I've got a small DB (max size 2GB) on SQL Server 2000 (yes, I know).

The problem is that the database has hit its size limit and can't grow anymore.

Looking through the tables there is one which has indexes totalling about 950 MB, fragmentation over 30%, and I want to trim this down.

Having gone for an index rebuild (and re-organise - was desperate) I am getting error messages due to a lack of space in primary to create pages.

I think that with later versions of SQL Server I could disable the index and then rebuild, which shouldn't require any additional space, however using the version I'm on this is not available.

Any thoughts on how rebuild indexes in this scenario?

---

OK, took advice to drop and re-create. Only problem I had is with the creating...!

See below for statement used, SQL SMS kept throwing a syntax error for line 9 near a '(', don't think it likes the options, which is odd, seeing as I was lazy and got SMS to generate the script itself from the original index... As you may have noticed, I'm no DBA!

```
USE Database

GO

ALTER TABLE [db1].[_tbl]

ADD  CONSTRAINT [ck_unique] 

UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 

(
    [DateID] ASC,
    [LRN] ASC,
    [Activity] ASC,
    [DateON] ASC
)

WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) 

ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

---

Tell you what, looking at these options I think I might be able to get away without using them. Won't most of them apply by default?

---

Welcome to how I work! Have entered statement as above but without the 'with' section.

Now looking through the GUI on SQL Server Manageblah I can see that at least some of the options are OK.

PAD_INDEX is Off, set to recompute statistics on, sort in tempdb is off, so:

do I need to make some changes to reflect the other options? i.e.:

```
IGNORE_DUP_KEY=OFF, ONLINE=OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS=ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS=ON
```

Really want to go pub->taxi->home->bed now!!!

Comment: The [SQL Server 8 limits table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.100).aspx) suggest the limit is much higher than 2 GiB. What kind of 2 GiB limit are you talking about?

Comment: Not 2008! 8! LOL - Old version from 2000, think maybe MSDE 2GiB limit imposed by license

Comment: Are you talking a limitation at DB level or at table level?

Comment: Drop the index and recreate it. Not for the clustered index, though.

Comment: @usr - that is what I was going to leave as a desperate last measure, don't want to have to recover db from .bak today if/when I bugger it up, and I'm averse to an out of hours fiddle tomorrow. Have two non-clustered indexes which are over 30% fragmentation, the clustered one is fine at 1.5% I think. So might just have to bite the bullet and start dropping....

Comment: You could copy all rows to a temp table and truncate the fragmented table after that. Then, copy back. This is quite error prone though and I'd rather not do it on a live database. It also assumes that you have tempdb space.

Comment: If you are using SQL 2000, the following options in your WITH clause were not available then: ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON. Try the options again, without those 3, but with FILLFACTOR = 100.

Comment: @drunkeneggs, forgot to mention, you want SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON so that it doesn't use local DB space.

Comment: You're going to run out of space very soon again if you're now struggling to the extent that rebuilding indexes is the only option you have left to free up space. You'll either need to start archiving data, or consider upgrading to something that allows you more space. The newer version of SQL Server have Express, which allows for up to 10 GB of data, and it'd be pretty straightforward to import (backup on 2000, restore on new server).

Comment: The only caveat would be depreciated code/functionality or other functionality if your database heavily relies on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are upto recreating index, you can use

```
USE DATABASE

DECLARE @TableName varchar(255) 

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR 

SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables 

WHERE table_type = 'base table' 

OPEN TableCursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 

BEGIN 

DBCC DBREINDEX(@TableName,' ',90) 

FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName 

END 

CLOSE TableCursor 

DEALLOCATE TableCursor
```

If this completed with errors then try

```
dbcc checkdb(DatabaseName,repair_allow_data_loss)
```

I've been always using this to reindex my databases sized around 2 GB. Hope this helps